# How to have comparison with CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, case

```
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN @TypeFatt <> -1 
            THEN docAM.typCIGA = @TypeFatt 
            ELSE docAM.typCIGA > @TypeFatt 
    END
```

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Why?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Depends on **what** RDBMS you're really using - please add a relevant tag! But in most RDBMS, `CASE` is an **expression** that simply returns a single, atomic value - you cannot use it to conditionally return and execute one block of code versus another .....

Comment: CASE statement syntax dictates that you can have condition after WHEN and result after THEN, you are trying to compare the values where the syntax expects result , please change your logic accordingly, if you want to have comparison based on a condition then you need to have another nested CASE statement(s)

Comment: @marc_s, I'd expect most rdbms to return the result of the _boolean expression_ `docAM.typCIGA = @TypeFatt` if @TypeFatt <> -1. However, I'd never write such query.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to use regular `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` *expressions* in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (@TypeFatt <> -1 AND docAM.typCIGA = @TypeFatt)
   OR (@TypeFatt = -1  AND docAM.typCIGA > @TypeFatt)
```